# Log4J: Parse errors in log4j.xml

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I am starting to work log4j in my projects, and I have right now this configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log4j:configuration debug="true" xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
  <appenders>
    <console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <patternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </console>
  </appenders>
  <loggers>
    <root level="error">
      <appenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </root>
  </loggers>
</log4j:configuration>
```

but when I deploy the application, I get this error:

```
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 2 and column 82
log4j:WARN O elemento-raiz do documento "log4j:configuration" deve corresponder à raiz de DOCTYPE "null".
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 2 and column 82
log4j:WARN O documento é inválido: nenhuma gramática encontrada.
log4j:WARN Unrecognized element appenders
log4j:WARN Unrecognized element loggers
```

while this two messages are displayed too:

```
log4j: reset attribute= "".
log4j: Threshold ="".
```

anyone knows what's wrong with this configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after more search on the web, I find a working example (the one available in the [official site](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) don't work for me). This is the file which worked for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
  <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender"> 
    <param name="Target" value="System.out"/> 
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/> 
    </layout> 
  </appender> 

  <root> 
    <priority value ="debug" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="console" /> 
  </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: Same for me. Do you know the reason behind it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/"
```

and remove the log4j prefix on the configuration tags

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true">
  <appenders>
    <console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <patternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </console>
  </appenders>
  <loggers>
    <root level="error">
      <appenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </root>
  </loggers>
</configuration>
```